# How to get ids of checked checkboxes that are generated dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is that when i click on the button after checking some checkboxes, the result shows that, there is a loop problem. the id of the last checked box have been push into the array instead.

My html looks like this:

```
<h1>Batch Testing</h1>

<div id="batch_schedule_wraper"></div>
<input type="button" id="getCheckedBoxtBtn" value="Get Checked Ids" />
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#getCheckedBoxtBtn').on('click', function() {

    var selected = [];

    $("div#batch_schedule_wraper input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
      }
    });

    alert(selected);
  });

  var sortedIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {

    $("#batch_schedule_wraper").append("<div class='checkbox'>" +
      "<label class='block'>" +
      "<input name='form-field-checkbox' type='checkbox' class='ace input-lg remove_widget' id=''/>" +
      "<span class='lbl bigger-120'>Batch</span>" +
      " </label>" +
      "</div>"

      +
      "</div>");
    $("[name='form-field-checkbox']").attr("id", sortedIds[i]);

  }
});
```

Comment: What loop problem? Try to be specific.

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here is:
You are appending a check box element into your div, and then setting id for all the check boxes that has name as "form-field-checkbox" inside your div. So it sets the same id for all the check boxes inside the div.

So at the end of your loop, all your check boxes will have the same id: "10".

You can solve it by setting id just for the current element and append it in your div.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {

    $("#batch_schedule_wraper").append("<div class='checkbox'>" +
      "<label class='block'>" +
      "<input name='form-field-checkbox' type='checkbox' class='ace input-lg remove_widget' id='" + sortedIds[i] + "'/>" +
      "<span class='lbl bigger-120'>Batch</span>" +
      " </label>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>");
  }
```

To bind event on individual check box, do this

```
    for (var i = 0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {

  var $checkDiv = $("<div class='checkbox'>" +
      "<label class='block'>" +
      "<input name='form-field-checkbox' type='checkbox' class='ace input-lg remove_widget' id='" + sortedIds[i] + "'/>" +
      "<span class='lbl bigger-120'>Batch</span>" +
      " </label>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>");

      $checkDiv.find("input").on("change", function(evt) {
            //do whatever you want
            //alert($(this).attr("id"));
      });

    $("#batch_schedule_wraper").append($checkDiv);
  }
```

Comment: I will like to mark your answer as the correct one, though other contributors also got it right but you answer came first. However can you please explain to me, how i can get event on a particular checkbox, hence i do not know there id eg.     $(document).on('change',"#UNKNOWN_ID", function(){

        $(this).prop('disabled', true); alert($(this).prop('id')) });

Comment: You can get the event by  `$(document).on('change',"#UNKNOWN_ID", function(evt){ console.log(evt); });` . Get the element by `$(evt.target)`.

Comment: Now that i can get the ids of all the checked checkboxes into an array, is there a way i can alert the ids individually, when each one is checked. I mean how i can handle individual checkbox in onchange event. seen that there ids can not be determine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you can really code! This now gives me all i have been looking, for the past three days!                     $(document).on('change',".checkboxClass", function(evt){
                            var target = $(evt.target);   
                            alert($(target).prop('id'));
                            
                            evt.preventDefault()
                    });

Comment: Thanks for the update, it reduces my code though and i learnt more syntax and semantics of jquery. Your update does not give me an expected result. I am sending the ids into ajax and on success i need to disable the checkbox but, $(this).prop('disabled',true); does not work, however the evt.target works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

since you used this code `$("[name='form-field-checkbox']").attr("id", sortedIds[i]);` which will set same id for all the checkbox due to same name attribute. Try the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sortedIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {

    $("#batch_schedule_wraper").append("<div class='checkbox'>" +
      "<label class='block'>" +
      "<input name='form-field-checkbox' type='checkbox' class='ace input-lg remove_widget' id='"+ sortedIds[i] +"'/>" +
      "<span class='lbl bigger-120'>Batch</span>" +
      " </label>" +
      "</div>"
      +
      "</div>");

  }

  $('#getCheckedBoxtBtn').on('click', function() {

    var selected = [];

    $("body div#batch_schedule_wraper input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
      }
    });

    console.log(selected);
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the checkboxes dynamically you are setting the `id` attribute of all of the created elements with the same value when you do this: `$("[name='form-field-checkbox']").attr("id", sortedIds[i]);`

Instead you can set the id in your loop like this:

```
// ...
"<input name='form-field-checkbox' type='checkbox' class='ace input-lg remove_widget' id='"+ sortedIds[i] +"'/>" +
//...
```

Also your query to get selected checkbox ids can be simplified:

```
var selected = $("div#batch_schedule_wraper input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function () {
    return $(this).attr("id");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually lies in your code where you assign the ids. You say `$("[name='form-field-checkbox']").attr("id", sortedIds[i]);` in *every* iteration and selector you've used basically targets ***all*** the DOM elements with `[name='form-field-checkbox']`. So, what happens is you're assigning the same id to all the matching elements every time and the last assigned id, 10 in your case, stays assigned to all.

The below snippet should help solve your problem. I've appended the id while creating the element itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $('#getCheckedBoxtBtn').on('click', function() {

    var selected = [];

    $("div#batch_schedule_wraper input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
      }
    });

    alert(selected);
  });

  var sortedIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {

    $("#batch_schedule_wraper").append("<div class='checkbox'>" +
      "<label class='block'>" +
      "<input name='form-field-checkbox' type='checkbox' class='ace input-lg remove_widget' id='" + sortedIds[i] + "'/>" +
      "<span class='lbl bigger-120'>Batch</span>" +
      " </label>" +
      "</div>"

      +
      "</div>");

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Batch Testing</h1>

<div id="batch_schedule_wraper"></div>
<input type="button" id="getCheckedBoxtBtn" value="Get Checked Ids" />
```

Comment: Sir, your answer is correct.  However can you please explain to me, how i can get event on a particular checkbox, hence i do not know there id eg. $(document).on('change',"#UNKNOWN_ID", function(){ $(this).prop('disabled', true); alert($(this).prop('id')) })

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically generated element, you can get the element by class, not ids as id should be unique for each dom element. e.g `$('.your_class_name')`. Here I add a class say `'checkboxClass'` for each checkbox and iterate over the checkbox.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#getCheckedBoxtBtn').on('click',function(){
       var selected = [];
       $('.checkboxClass').each(function(){
          if($(this).is(':checked')){
       selected.push($(this).prop('id'));
          }
       });
      alert(selected);                       
   });

   var sortedIds= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
   for (var i=0; i < sortedIds.length; i++) {
       $("#batch_schedule_wraper").append("<div class='checkbox'>"
  +"<label class='block'>"
  +"<input name='form-field-checkbox'  type='checkbox' class='ace input-lg remove_widget checkboxClass' id='"+sortedIds[i]+"'/>"
  +"<span class='lbl bigger-120'>Batch</span>"
  +" </label>"+"</div>"+"</div>");                         
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="batch_schedule_wraper"></div>
<input type="button" id="getCheckedBoxtBtn" value="Get Checked Ids"/>
```